# Как сделать правильно hover на jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Имеем такую разметку :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#author").hover(function() {
    $(this).after($('<div class="inner"></div>'));
  });
});
```

```css
span.mime {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#author {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(0 + 20px);
  left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="author" class="mime"><a href="">Имя Фамилия</a></span>
```

Косяк в том что :

1) как вставить inner таким образом что бы span#author был родителем ?

2) как сделать hover , что бы он был как на css, убрал мышь и блок опять пропал но так же сохранялось возможность работы внутри блока inner ?

3) или как это сделать более лучше?

блок вставляется на jquery что бы не вмешиваться в html разметку

Comment: блок inner - динамический?

Comment: В место span используй другой элемент...  Так как блочный элемент вставлять в строчный запрещено...

Comment: @KirillKorushkin да он динамичный ...там может быть всё что угодно ... ссылки на профиль и прочую лабуду ...

Comment: @Air да заменить span можно но не желательно

Comment: @Максим Ленский а если вместо div использовть span display:block?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin я так и сделал но только inline-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как сделать лучше - ответ на этот вопрос не однозначный и зависит от условий. Можно вот так- при первом ховере блок inner добавляется в span. далее лишь прячется/показывается:

```js
$(function() {

    $("#author").hover(
    
        function() {
            if(!$(this).find('.inner').length) {
                $(this).append('<span class="inner" style="display:block"></span>');
            }else{
                 $(this).find('.inner').show();     
            }
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('.inner').hide();
        }
    );
});
```

```css
span.mime {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#author {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(0 + 20px);
  left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="author" class="mime"><a href="">Имя Фамилия</a></span>
```

Comment: при этом блок вставляется внутрь тега span ?т.е span родитель для блока ?

Comment: @Максим Ленский  да. при первом ховере блок inner добавляется в span. далее лишь прячется/показывается

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавить внутрь - `wrap.append(inner)` [док.](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
2. Наведение. Cмысл в том что hover состоит из 2-х функций (запись через запятую). Первая - навели на элемент, вторая - увели мышь с элемента. И второй вариант как угодно можно реализовать: `hide()`, `remove()`, `css({'dispaly': 'none' ...` , `slideUp()` [док.](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

   `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )`
3. Можно так:

```js
$("#author").hover(
  function() { // навели
    $(this).append('<div class="inner"></div>');
  },
  function(){ // убрали
    $(this).find('.inner').remove();
  }
);
```

```css
span.mime {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#author {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(0 + 20px);
  left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<span id="author" class="mime"><a href="">Имя Фамилия</a></span>
```

Можно просто с помощью css:

```css
span.mime {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#author {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(0 + 20px);
  left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  
  display: none;
}

#author:hover .inner {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span id="author" class="mime">
  <a href="">Имя Фамилия</a>
  
  <span class="inner"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: на css не надо ... я умею на css , надо встроить блок и показывать его по hover но аналогично как и в css , но на jquery на hover показывается но не пропадает , у меня по крайней мере

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, да это на всякий случай если кто не знает))

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, `на hover показывается но не пропадает , у меня по крайней мере` на жуквери смыслк в том что hover из 2-х функций состоит (запись через запятую) , первая - навели на элемент, вторая - увели мышь с элемента. И второй вариант как угодно можно реализовать - `hide`, `remove`, `css({'dispaly': 'none' ...` , `slideUp` ...

Comment: а ну я затупил ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Вроде это можно и без jQuery сделать, разместив заранее элемент `.inner` и написав условие его видимости:

```
#author:not(:hover) .inner {
  display: none;
}
```

Сниппет:

```css
/* новые стили: */

#author:not(:hover) .inner {
  display: none;
}

/* конец новых стилей: */


span.mime {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#author {
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(0 + 20px);
  left: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="author" class="mime">
  <a href="">Имя Фамилия</a>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</span>
```

Comment: нее ... мне не надо его в вёрстку вставлять ... я это и сам могу сделать на css

Comment: не очень понимаю зачем, ну да ладно

Comment: используется голый html , просто DOCTYPE И BODY и всё ... а остальное вставляется все возможными путями и способами